# Android: simplest url download without progress bar

Tags: java, android, http, download

I have tried to implement over 10-15 different download mechanisms for android java, I have not been able to succeed at all.
I don't care about progress bars or background processes.
I just want one functional download code in fewest lines possible
and I want it to download a binary file (foreground) to the directory in the device wherever it can be accessed as

```
File pf = new File("filename");
if (pf.exists())  { ... }
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this (modified from [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/download-an-http-file-to-sdcard-with-progress-notification)):

```
try {
        URL url = new URL("http://url.com");

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.connect();

        //THIS IS WHERE YOU GET THE DIRECTORY TO SAVE TO
        File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        //THIS IS WHERE YOU WILL SET THE FILE NAME
        File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"somefile.txt");

        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        //create a buffer...
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength = 0;

        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        }
        fileOutput.close();

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You may also need to add permissions to access the phone directory:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
</manifest>
```

For information on accessing certain folders on the internal directory, see the android developer page: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteInternalStorage

In fact, the solution on that page is also fairly short:

```
String filename = "myfile";
String string = "Hello world!";
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
  outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
  outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Note that this solution does not require any progress updates, stream checking, asynchronous downloading, etc, so beware for general application; this solution is simply geared toward the question asked.

Comment: Try adding this permission along with the other permissions: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: this crashes the application, what can be the problem? error log: [link](http://pastebin.com/fEKP5pBD)

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> already exists. i really appreciate the help. I am doing this inside mainactivity btw.

Comment: is that your take at `fewest lines`?